# On build Web API localization resx could not create the folder on obj

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, localization

I was looking for Web API localization standard practice with resx files. Then i have found a solution on github [WebApiLocalization](https://github.com/damienbod/WebAPILocalization). This solution I liked very much and want to implement it on my own project.

On this repository there has a `Resources` folder and inside on this folder there has as default three resx file named

```
AmazingResource.de-CH.resx
AmazingResource.fr-FR.resx
AmazingResource.resx
```

For testing I added another resource file name `AmazingResource.bn-BN.resx` and I have modified the **LanguageMessageHandler** class with bellow code

```
 private const string LangbnBN = "bn-BN";
 private const string LangdeCH = "de-CH";
 private const string LangfrFR = "fr-FR";
 private const string LangenGB = "en-GB";

 private readonly List<string> _supportedLanguages = new List<string
 {
      LangbnBN, 
      LangdeCH, 
      LangfrFR, 
      LangenGB

 };
```

But the problem is it is not working for my resource.

Then I tried to find why it is not working. And after spending too much time I have find the problem

The problem is after build on obj folder the bn-BN folder is not created with the resource.dd file .

[Please Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG7s6.png)

My humble request is why this problem and how can I solve this?